# How to reproduce the JavaScript of an XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, firebug

A lot of browser extensions give the option to view and analyze XHRs. The DevTools in Firefox for example have an *Edit and Resend* button for requests, but that's not what I need.

I need to know the **exact** JavaScript code that runs when I resend a request.
I need this for a Youtube user script, but the JavaScript code on Youtube is so obfuscated that I could never reproduce the request from that.

What add-on or extension could tell me the exact JavaScript that runs when I resend a request?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no tool that outputs the JavaScript for an XHR.

Instead of relying on tools you can achieve that by looking at the request data and recreate the request by yourself [adding all the headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Setting_HTTP_request_headers) and the body. There is [a lot of documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) on how to do that.

To get the request data open the *Network* panel of the Firefox DevTools (e.g. via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>). Then execute the request, so it will get listed within the panel. Click on the request. The *Request headers* section includes all headers you need to append to your XHR via [`XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader%28%29). If you need to send POST data, you may use a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object to do so.

Comment: thank you, but the problem is i dont know at all how to do that. wouldnt the "Debugger" in firefox developer tools show the javascript if i resend a request? since the request's javascript has to run in the browser after all

Comment: The DevTools create the request internally, they don't show you the JavaScript behind it. They only show the request within their *Network* panel. Firebug has an option called [*Break on XHR*](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel#Requests) allowing you to stop the script at the code doing the request, i.e. at the [`XMLHttpRequest.send()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#send%28%29) line, though you'll just see that line, not the data behind the request, and as it's minified you won't see much, anyway. I fear you need to learn how to create XHRs.